# Generic Factory Method Casting Issue

Tags: c#, generics, factory

Trying to create a factory to return a generic interface (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386586/c-sharp-generic-interface-and-factory-pattern)) but getting the error:

> Can't implicitly convert `IFinancialsSyncService<Vendor, QuickBooksVendor>` to `IFinancialsSyncService<TEntity, TQuickBooksEntity>`. Anexplicit conversion exists, are you missing a cast?

```
public class QuickBooksEntityServiceFactory
{
    public IFinancialsSyncService<TEntity, TQuickBooksEntity> Create<TEntity, TQuickBooksEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IEntity, IFinancials, new()
        where TQuickBooksEntity : class, IQuickBooksEntity
    {

        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(QuickBooksVendor))
        {
            return new QuickbooksVendorService();
        }


        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

The service confirms to the `IFinancialsSyncService` interface:

```
public class QuickbooksVendorService : IFinancialsSyncService<Vendor, QuickBooksVendor>
```

However, if I cast it explicitly, I get a `Cast is redundant` error along with the first error still.

```
return (IFinancialsSyncService<Vendor, QuickBooksVendor>)new QuickbooksVendorService();
```

So the error is confusing me. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is what I'm trying to simplify. There are several instances similar to this also that call other common methods of the interface.

```
switch (enumDataElement)
{
    //Export jobs
    case DataElement.Item:
        var itemService = new QuickbooksItemService();
        exportResult = itemService.UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId(session, response, EntityId, intUserId);
        break;

    case DataElement.Vendor:
        var VendorService = new QuickbooksVendorService();
        exportResult = UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId(new QuickbooksVendorService(),session, response, EntityId, intUserId);
        break;

    case DataElement.Bill:
        var billService = new QuickbooksBillService();
        exportResult = billService.UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId(session, response, intUserId);
        break;

    case DataElement.PurchaseOrder:
        var qbPOService = new QuickbooksPurchaseOrderService();
        exportResult = qbPOService.UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId(session, response, intUserId);           
        break;

    case DataElement.SalesReceipt:
        var salesReceiptService = new QuickbooksSalesReceiptService();
        exportResult = salesReceiptService.UpdateStratusEntityWithFinancialsId(session, response, intUserId);
        break;
}
```

And replace it with something like:

```
var qbEntityService = EntityServiceFactory.Create(enumDataElement);
```

What would this factory look like?

Comment: What is Vendor Type? Does it implements IEntity?

Comment: [MUCH Simplified DotNetFIddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/auemb2).

Comment: Please check your QuickbooksVendorService correctly implements IFinancialsSyncService. Also check in your generic method TEntity implements IEntity and IFinancials and TQuickBooksEntity  implements IQuickBooksEntity.

Comment: @maxspan yes, they all implement the correct interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with Liskov's Substitution Principle.  Imagine that your Generic type is instead a property of the interface:

```
public interface IFinancials { }

public interface IFinancialsSyncService
{
  IFinancials Financials { get; set; }
}
```

Now we implement this interfaces:

```
public class Financials : IFinancials {}

public class FinancialsSyncService : IFinancialSyncService
{
  public Financials Financials { get; set; }
}
```

This results in a compiler error:

> Compilation error: 'Program.FinancialsSyncService' does not implement interface member 'Program.IFinancialsSyncService.Financials'. 'Program.FinancialsSyncService.Financials' cannot implement 'Program.IFinancialsSyncService.Financials' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Program.IFinancials'.

Both problems have the same issue.  In my example, the interface states that the result is of type `IFinancials` but is a more specific derived type `Financials` and even though any valid value that is placed in the property fulfills the interface, it cannot be replaced with any value derived from `IFinancials` only types that derive from `Financials`.

So if your code looked like:

```
public interface IFinancialsSyncService<TEntity>
   where TEntity : IEntity
{
  TEntity Financials { get; set; }
}
```

and you create a class:

```
public class QuickbooksVendorService : IFinancialSyncService<Vendor>
{
  public Vendor Financials { get; set; }
}
```

However, now `QuickbooksVendorService` is a `IFinancialSyncService<Vendor>` not a `IFinancialSyncService<TEntity>` because the property is the derived type.  Even if you didn't have this specific property it still leads to the same problem that generic type is more specific than the interface.

Comment: Thanks Erik, so you can't return a more specific type. I have several other entity related services similar to `QuickBooksVendorService` that all conform to the same interface. I was looking for a factory to return the correct one of these, based on an input type. I only need to use a couple of methods that are common to them all that is part of the interface definition. So how can I create a factory to return one of these services...what would be the common return type of the factory? Or am I approaching this the wrong way? Note, updated question to show what I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: I'd question why you'd want to return a Generic Interface `InterfaceOf<T>` instead of just the interface `Interface`.  You haven't really said who's consuming the result so it's hard to know.

Comment: Yes, I was able to remove the methods from the interface that return `TEntity` and `TQuickBooksEntity` and removing those qualifiers of the interface. The factory works fine then returning just the interface `IFinancialSyncService`. But I would like to restore these methods to the interface. The main reason is, as this is an adapter type project, it is retrieving a QuickBooks entity, like an Invoice, then converting it into our app's version of an Invoice that we then import into our app database.

Comment: @ChadRichardson you need to fix lines 59 and 62.

Comment: @ChadRichardson Actually there is no point to your generic declarations.  See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQq5nn).

Comment: Thanks Erik...almost there...but now why is the factory returning null? [updated fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dRHg2L)

Comment: The cast of the service is resulting in null. `var service = new CustomerSyncService();   
   if(service == null) Console.WriteLine("Service Factory service == null!!!"); //service is not null here.
   return service as ISyncService<IQBEntity, IEntity>; //this casting results in null`.

Comment: @ChadRichardson Removed more generics that were unused.  [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4kl9Rs).

Answer (score 0):

use Factory method and Adapter pattern

```
   [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {

        [Test]
        public void Go()
        {
            var qbItem = Export(1);
            var qbVendor= Export(2);
            var qbSales= Export(3);
        }

        public qbEntityService Export(int number)
        {
            var qb = Class1.Create(number);
            return qb.UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId();
        }

        public static IEntityService Create(int enumDataElement)
        {
            switch (enumDataElement)
            {
                case 1:
                    return new QuickbooksItemService();
                case 2:
                    return new QuickbooksVendorService();
                case 3:
                    return new QuickbooksSalesReceiptServiceAdapter(new QuickbooksSalesReceiptService());
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IEntityService
    {
        qbEntityService UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId();
    }

    public class qbEntityService
    {
    }

    public class QuickbooksItemService : IEntityService
    {
        public qbEntityService UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am QuickbooksItemService, performing UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId");
            return new qbEntityService();
        }
    }

    public class QuickbooksVendorService : IEntityService
    {
        public qbEntityService UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am QuickbooksVendorService, performing UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId");
            return new qbEntityService();
        }
    }

    public class QuickbooksSalesReceiptService
    {
        public qbEntityService UpdateStratusEntityWithFinancialsId()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am QuickbooksSalesReceiptService, performing UpdateStratusEntityWithFinancialsId");
            return new qbEntityService();
        }
    }


    public class QuickbooksSalesReceiptServiceAdapter : IEntityService
    {
        private QuickbooksSalesReceiptService adaptee;

        public QuickbooksSalesReceiptServiceAdapter(QuickbooksSalesReceiptService adaptee)
        {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }

        public qbEntityService UpdateMozzoEntityWithFinancialsId()
        {
            return adaptee.UpdateStratusEntityWithFinancialsId();
        }
    }
```