# How to create factory class which will return the derived types of common interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I have an Interface and it is implemented by many classes. Each class also has its own set of properties which are not present in interface. Now, if I want to design a factory which returns of type interface, I cannot set some of the derived class properties as they are not member of interface.

How to address this scenario?

Comment: one way to do it is to the factory method generic

Comment: Can you please provide any link describing  factory method generic ?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39386748/9748260

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Generic Interface and Factory Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386586/c-sharp-generic-interface-and-factory-pattern)

Comment: That's not true.  You can create and return an instance of any derived type that implements the supertype interface of the return type. The return value must be downcasted to get the original subtype. A generic factory **where the generic type describes the return type** is not recommended. It is an anti-pattern as you have to perform type checks inside factory to select the right instance to return. It is more convenient to introduce a dedicated factory for each factored return type.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an Interface like

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and implementations like

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Something { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondClass : MyInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    decimal SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

you can create your class in the factory like

```
public class MyFactory
{
    public MyInterface createMyClass() 
    {
        return new MyClass() { Name = "foo", Something = 42 };
    }

    public MyInterface createMySecondClass() 
    {
        return new MySecondClass() { Name = "bar", SomethingElse = 4.2M };
    }
}
```

Of course this way you can't access the members you don't have declared in your interface.

```
var something = myFactory.createMyClass().Something;
```

This wouldn't work. You can only access the name property:

```
var name = myFactory.createMyClass().Name;
```

If you would want to access the special property of your class, you would have to cast your interface to the actual class:

```
var something = ((MyClass)myFactory.createMyClass()).Something;
```